# Math.Ceiling weird behaviour

Tags: c#

I'm having a weird problem and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

```
decimal pages = Math.Ceiling((decimal)(927/1027));
MessageBox.Show(pages.ToString());
```

927/1027 = 0.902..... so this should return 1 right?

Instead I get 0.

But when I directly input the value to Ceiling,

```
decimal pages = Math.Ceiling((decimal)(0.902));
MessageBox.Show(pages.ToString());
```

I get 1 as expected. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're doing integer division here - change the integers to decimals, rather than the result of their division

Comment: change `927/1027` to `927.0/1027.0` to do double division and keep the precision.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`927/1027` is an integer expression that evaluates to the `int` with value `0`.

If you want a decimal calculation then you should do it like this:

```
Math.Ceiling(927m/1027m);
```

The `m` suffix indicates a literal of type `decimal`.

But that itself would be somewhat odd since `Math.Ceiling` receives a floating point parameter as input. So, if you are using `Math.Ceiling` then I think that you really want to use floating point division. Like this:

```
Math.Ceiling(927.0/1027.0);
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel enlightened now :D

Comment: Good. I'm glad we could help. Is there any reason why you were using `decimal`. That's normally used, for example, for financial calculations. For scientific, engineering etc., then floating point is to be preferred.

Comment: No reason. I'm one of those self taught programmers that doesn't know anything properly. But now I know :) Just out of curiosity, a single precision float occupies 32 bits right? so what about a decimal? does it require more or lesser memory?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) has the answer. A C# `decimal` is 128 bits. The size of the variable is probably not the most important factor.

Comment: Thanks. So using floats are more economical in terms of memory right?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I doubt that memory is key. Getting the right answer is probably more important.